# apply gaussian blur to an image ussing python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to replicate the following smoothing of an image using a Gaussian filter (images from a journal):
[image]

In the paper says that in order to get from the left image to the right image I have to apply a gaussian fiter with values x,y = 1,...,100 and sigma = 14 to obtain the "best resuts"

I have developed the following program in python to try to achieve this smoothing:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = ndimage.imread('left2.png')
img = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=(14), order=0)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

for some reason the result obtained is not similar to the picture in the right. 
Can someone please point out what do I have to modify in the program to get from the left image to the right image?

Thank you.

Comment: The right-hand image does not look like a sig=14pix blur of the left. Perhaps the authors described their method inaccurately.

Comment: Yes that might be correct, but anyway I would like to know what did they do to obtain the right image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here:

Because they mention that their x and y values range from 0-100, they're probably applying a "sigma = 14 *unit* blur" instead of a "sigma = 14 *pixel* blur".

The `sigma` parameter in `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter` is in pixel units. If I'm correct about the author's intent, you'll need to scale the sigma parameter you pass in.

If the authors specified that both `x` and `y` ranged from 0-100, the sigma in the x and y directions will be different, as your input data appears have a different number of rows than columns (i.e. it isn't a perfectly square image).

Perhaps try something similar to this?

```
nrows, ncols = img.shape
sigma = (14 * nrows / 100.0, 14 * ncols / 100.0)
img = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=sigma)
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Thank you for your answer. Acording to your code, there is only two values of sigma for 14 * nrows / 100 (x axis)  and 14 * ncols / 100.0 (y axis) how are the values are being changed (from 1 to 100) according to your code? I ran the following code `img = ndimage.imread('left2.png')
print img.shape
nrows = img.shape[0]
print nrows
ncols = img.shape[1]
print ncols
sigma = (14 * nrows / 100.0, 14 * ncols / 100.0)
img = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=sigma)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()` you can find the image in https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpur6xuzqh1xlur/left2.png?dl=0

Comment: When executing the previous code I obtained the following problem: RuntimeError: sequence argument must have length equal to input rank