# Gaussian Filter on Map with coordinates (Basemap)

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am following an paper (https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2017JB014307) and figure out that I need to use a gaussian filter on map.

In the paper, they mapped spatial resolution of 1km with using linear interpolation using  gaussian filter with 300km full width.

When I read this part, I thought the spatial resolution and width can be controlled when I use gaussian filter.

But figured out that many examples are related to pictures(.jpg, .png) and hard to find which used basemap.

I have used basemap when plotting data.

The data I have has a form like below.

```
Longitude, Latitude, Z
127.4947 34.54534 0.3
127.8213 34.54153 0.5
127.21 34.3 0.9
127.8256 34.43295 0.1
127.4341 34.46761 0.6
...
```

I extracted Longitude column to X_list, Latitude column to Y_list, Z to Z_list.

It is scatter plot but I want to it as smoothed map as below (example). (I am not allowed to upload directly yet)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnH9N.png)

I brought the example from [apply gaussian blur to an image ussing python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29236249/16699117) .

So what I want to do is plotting data on basemap with gaussian filter..but so hard to find the way to do.

If you know the way, could you please let me know how to solve this?

###Plot code

```
la=35.12
ua=35.6
ln=127.1
un=128
m_lat=(la+ua)/2
m_lon=(ln+un)/2
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
m=Basemap(projection='lcc', lat_0=m_lat, lon_0=m_lon, resolution='f', llcrnrlon=ln, llcrnrlat=la, urcrnrlon=ua, epsg=4326)
m.scatter(X_list, Y_list, marker='^', c=Z_list, cmap='bwr', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague, but could be made very specific.  You should add a link to the paper you are following, some example data (could be a 10x10 array) and some minimal code that shows what you have done so far

Comment: @VinceW. Sorry for confusing. I edited the question.